# Appending elements generated by a for loop into an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, for-loop

I want to generate an array containing all the elements produced by a for loop. I haven't found anything relevant or helpful in the NumPy manual or stackoverflow. This is the problematic part of the code.

```
import numpy as np

for i in range(0,26):
    d = np.random.uniform(i,i+1.75)
    empty = np.array([])
    all = np.append(empty, d)
    print all
```

I have tried both append and concatenate, both of them just print 25 arrays but only store to `all` the last one.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Moses's answer works fine, but you can achieve this directly in numpy. `np.random.uniform` also takes a size parameter. [See documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html). Your code can therefore be simplified to:

```
all = np.random.uniform(0, 1.75, size=(26,))
all += np.arange(26)
```

The trick here is to realise that `np.random.uniform(0, 1.75) + 1` is the same as `np.random.uniform(1, 2.75)`

The second line is to account for the indices in your loop. The result will be:

```
array([  0.82259558,   1.07737171,   3.56331306,   3.44506941,
         5.36435903,   6.43062515,   7.4293016 ,   8.62581585,
         9.64664137,  10.11875821,  10.04800508,  12.03356491,
        13.16818327,  14.12761814,  15.09009053,  15.96770449,
        17.0981378 ,  17.47152708,  18.15557107,  20.13834956,
        21.22972932,  22.15797838,  22.97552168,  23.09385798,
        24.17160732,  25.07440533])
```

This solution might be a little harder to wrap your head around, but it is a very powerful pattern when you want to do more complicated calculations. Please tell me if you don't understand it. And also, @Moses's solution is also correct!

Answer (score 1):

Your `all` should be placed outside the loop, so you can avoid overwriting previously written values and the value should be updated and not reassigned to  a new append with `empty`:

```
import numpy as np

all = np.array([])
for i in range(0,26):
    d = np.random.uniform(i,i+1.75)
    all = np.append(all, d)
    print all
```

Comment: @nikjohn You should also put `print all` outside of the loop